# conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string only on one of the server

Tags: sql-server-2008, query-performance

I have a sql query as follows:

```
select * from Txn_Master
where Txn_Type = 'TPD' and 
Txn_Date = Getdate() 
order by Txn_ID DESC
```

But in this sql-server query when i enter date manually like '01/06/2023' it shows data in table but whenever i enter getdate() function to get current date automatically it shows no data only shows blank table

Comment: Your question describes a blank result. So what is the relevance of the error message in the question title? Where does that come into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when i enter date manually like '01/06/2023' it shows data in table but whenever i enter getdate() function to get current date automatically it shows no data

[`GETDATE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) returns the current system timestamp as a `DATETIME` value (**date and time to the milliseconds**). That's obviously different than just the `DATE` value string you provided of `'01/06/2023'`. Your `Txn_Date` probably truly doesn't have any values with the same milliseconds as the instant in time when you ran the query with `GETDATE()`.

To make your query work with `GETDATE()`, you need to cast it to just a `DATE` data type like so:

```
select * from Txn_Master
where Txn_Type = 'TPD' and 
Txn_Date = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()) 
order by Txn_ID DESC
```